# strange mySQL connection/ write issue

Tags: php, sql

I don't know if this is relevant in anyway but here goes:
I had a script working fine called insert.php and so I then moved onto creating a script that could delete rows. after some testing I noticed the script i was using was connecting to the database but then seemed unable to make any changes. I then ran the MySQL query in phpmyadmin to check it was valid and it worked. I then went back to my insert.php script and that had stopped working too. I then looked at my index.php page and that was inserting the database just fine. Does anyone have the foggiest what might be happening here? I must stress that it 1000% isn't a connection issue

index page which pulls information from the server (this is at the top of the document:

```
   <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxx","xxx");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}           
?>
```

Connection within insert.php

```
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=GLO12408958DB';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'xxx';
    //
    // DB connection was made
    //
    try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password,
    array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    die(json_encode(array('outcome' => true)));
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex){
    die(json_encode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')));
    }
```

connection within delete.php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxx","glo12408958db");
// Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
```

Comment: Your title says connection issue, and you end with "isn't a connection issue." I think we need to see more before we can be of any help.

Comment: I'll edit the OP with some code

Comment: edited the OP to show all the connections

Comment: Why do you have a `die()` statement after you open your PDO connection? And why are you using two different api's to talk to your database, PDO and mysqli?

Comment: You're mixing mysqli and PDO, which have different interfaces.  Unless you have a very compelling reason for using different libraries, you should pick one and stick with it.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it would have mattered seeing as they are separate files. also i copied that cope below the PDO just to make sure it was connecting it does. i get true

Comment: i think you have dbName problem, in insert.php you used GLO12408958DB and in delete.php you used glo12408958db why??

Answer (score 0):

A few things (the first is probably your problem...):

1. You are using different database names; on most linux / unix systems, mysql identifiers are [case sensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html). So `GLO12408958DB` is not the same as `glo12408958db`. Unless you are hosting on windows or a mac...
2. You are mixing 2 database api's, PDO and mysqli. You should stick to one although this should work if both are installed;
3. You have a `die()` statement after you open your PDO connection. Is that just for debugging or is that really there? If it is, remove it.

Comment: thank you greatly for your reply but I am running windows. the die was just for debugging.

Comment: @user248305 Is your web-server running windows?

Comment: I am running on a local server. which is windows